# Class SpreadsheetAppにはcloseメソッドがない。　何故？

Tags: google-apps-script

Class SpreadsheetAppにはopenメソッドが３種類ありますが、closeメソッドはありません。これは自動的にcloseされるということでしょうか？　明示的にcloseするまでopen状態を保っておくにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

こちらはGoogle側の開発者が命名したメソッド名なので正確なことは言えませんが、
ファイルシステムの様にファイルをopenして排他制御したりはしていないので、
概念上もメソッド上closeというものはありません。
openはただ単にSpreadsheetの実体を取得しているメソッドになります。